# Read integers from file using struct.unpack in Python

Tags: python, file-io, struct

Suppose I have a file name `num.txt` as below:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0
```

I want to read `3 integers` from this file, that is `1 2 3`.

I know that `struct.unpack` might do the trick, but I just cannot get it right.
Here is how I did it:

```
fp = open('num.txt', 'rb')
print struct.unpack('iii', fp.read(12))  #right?
```

Anyone can help me with this?

**PS**

This is how I got file num.txt:

```
fp = open('num.txt', 'wb')
fp.write('1 2 3 4 5\n6 7 8 9 0')
fp.close()
```

Comment: Are you sure that num.txt isn't a text file?

Comment: Did you look at the answers before doing your edit? We both correctly interpreted your situation -- you don't have binary data, so you don't use `struct`.

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `struct` to read numbers from a text file. It is for reading data from a binary file -- where the first byte is actually `0x01` rather than a byte order mark or the encoded value of the character `'1'`.

You just want

```
three_ints = [int(x) for x in numfile.readline().strip().split(' ')[:3]]
```

If you're only interested in the first three numbers, or

```
all_ints = [[int(x) for x in line.split()] for line in numfile]
```

if you want a `list` of `list`s of the `int`s on each line.

Comment: yes, you're right. But how could I do it using struct? Does it have something to do with the file num.txt?

Comment: @Alcott: Read the answers again. Then a third time. Keep reading them until "binary" sinks in.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, yes, it sinks in. But I kinda wonder How or Can I make those numbers in num.txt binary?

Comment: That doesn't even make any sense. If it's text then it's text, and should be treated as such.

Comment: @Alcott When you write the numbers like that, the values in the file aren't actually those numbers, but (most likely) the ASCII values of those characters. So if you read them back with `struct`, you'd get the ASCII value of a `1`, then the ASCII value of a space, then the ASCII value of a `2`. You need to write them something like `numfile.write(''.join(chr(x) for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]))` to be able to read them back in with `struct`.

Answer (score 4):

`struct` is used for C-style binary representations of numbers. If you have text representations instead then you should just pass them to `int()`.

```
>>> [int(x) for x in '1 2 3 4 5'.split()]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```